# Best Practice for updating fragment with data object (DTO)?

Tags: android

My fragment represents dynamic information which is obtained asynchronously. I am interested in how to provide the DAO/DTO to the fragment. Should the fragment maintain a reference to the DTO? What about updates. Should it request updated DTO and be the listener on these async calls or request that the activity make the requests and then update the fragment when the async response arrives?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a "best practice" way to do this in Android. There are many ways and many of them are valid.

My recommendation would be to create a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) that keeps track of changes in the data and report back to the fragment that requires it. Should be careful with this and make sure the service is only active when required, otherwise we can get background tasks that drain the battery.

The simplest way to register a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) when the fragment is visible (after onResume, remove in onPause). This is like the intent filters that you can set for activities in the manifest. Here is a nice example: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.htmlz

Once the receiver gets the intent there are 3 possible ways to procede.

- Create a DAO and access the data (possibly a bit slow)
- Use a ContentProvider and receive the new items in the intent sent to the receiver
- If your data is Serializable or Parcelable you can add the new new data to the sent intent. (Possibly the fastest)

**UPDATE**

---

There is a useful tool for this kind of task that I forgot to mention: [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)
They provide a simple way to handle data sources (like content providers).